# Clients don't receive email when using Paypal REST api send invoice

Tags: php, curl, paypal

i already created and sent an invoice to client then i used retrieve invoice to check. The status is SENT but client did not receive any invoice from mail. Here is my code:

```
$send = "curl -v -X 'POST' 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/INV2-DZF4-Y9AU-4L7U-ZF7W/send' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token . "'";
exec($send, $sendResult);
$receive = "curl -v -X 'GET' 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/INV2-DZF4-Y9AU-4L7U-ZF7W' -H 'Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token . "'";
exec($receive, $receiveResult);
$receiveResultReponse = json_decode(implode(" ", $receiveResult));
print_r($receiveResultReponse);($receiveResultReponse);
```

The response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => INV2-DZF4-Y9AU-4L7U-ZF7W
    [number] => 0122
    [status] => SENT
    [merchant_info] => stdClass Object
        (
...
    [metadata] => stdClass Object
        (
            [created_date] => 2015-08-31 02:22:21 PDT
            [first_sent_date] => 2015-08-31 02:22:22 PDT
            [last_sent_date] => 2015-08-31 02:22:22 PDT
            [payer_view_url] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi_bin/webscr?cmd=_pay-inv&viewtype=altview&id=INV2-DZF4-Y9AU-4L7U-ZF7W
        )

)
```

No invoice email receive from clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sandbox doesn't send emails...

> *The email address doesn't need to be a real email address; the Sandbox doesn't send any email outside of the Sandbox environment.*

REF: [Creating Sandbox Test Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/)

You can:

1. Check [Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/)
2. Login as your sandbox buyer in the [Paypal Sandbox site](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) - you should see the invoices that buyer received

Hth...